# CIFS Shares No Longer Automounting At Boot

Tags: arch-linux, mount, fstab, automounting, cifs

I have a couple of CIFS shares that used to automount successfully (on an Arch Linux box) at boot but have recently stopped doing so.

Example line from my fstab:

```
//192.168.66.21/home        /home/myuser/nas        cifs    users,_netdev,uid=myuser,gid=users,credentials=/etc/smbcred,sec=ntlmv2 0 0
```

I can mount the shares manually using `mount nas` and / or `sudo mount -a`

I tried adding `x-systemd.automount` to the fstab entry but this results in the following error:

```
CIFS: Unknown mount option "x-systemd.automount"
```

A possible culprit?: I installed `autofs` a few months ago then removed it. Maybe a complete red herring but could this somehow have had an effect on fstab?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but the error was caused by... I set the unreachable IP to `/etc/fstab`. That log never say "IP is wrong/unreachable/not respond". Just try `ping` to the IP first.